# Image stopes being responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, partial-views

I have a Datatables inside a bootstrap tabpanel

Page first loads and the active panel is displayed, then I click on the tab that contains the table and everything is fine, my images are responsive, like this:[image]

Then I click on another tab, and when I get back to my previous one, I get a non responsive image, like this:
[image]

When clicking a tab, I call a function that makes an ajax call that retuns a partial view. I insert the parial view as the tab content, This is how I do it:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
    var targetDivId = e.target.hash;
    if (targetDivId === '#myspesificdiv') {
        callAction(url, targetDivId);
    }
});

function callAction(url, divId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $(divId).html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

What's wrong? thanks

Comment: I think it's a CSS issue. Using CSS, force the image width or, better, force its parent width and set the image `max-width` property to `100%`. Other posibility is that you are loading the wrong images. Have you big and small images? Or is it always the same resized?

Comment: bootstrap's .img-responsive sets max-width: 100%;, height: auto; and display: block. It is the same image.

Comment: Can you append to your post the rendered html?

Answer (score 0):

Inspected the table in Google chrome, found out that at first, the th's width is set to 69px. In the second case it is set to 360px. I just fixed it at 69 and everything is ok now. I don't know why this happens.